# Do not show 'Test file: XXX.js' while testing casperjs file

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there any possibility(settings) or any way to do not show this text 'Test file: myfile.js' (Sky blue background colored text) while running `casperjs --includes=myinclude.js test myfile.js`. I do not want this to be displayed at first step on STDOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to do it, however I have just made a pull request to remove this output when there is only a single file being tested.

[Pull Request](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/566)

Comment: I saw https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/566 was reopened & raised query against this feature. But I hope if there is any cmd line option at least to stop showing would be better.